# How to return a dynamic list of widgets in SwiftUI WidgetBundleBuilder body

Tags: ios, swiftui, widgetkit

Is it possible to create a dynamic list of widgets inside the body of `WidgetBundle`? For example:

```
@main
struct HomeWidgetBundle: WidgetBundle {
    
    @WidgetBundleBuilder
    var body: some Widget {
        
        List<Widget> {
            ForEach (0..<10) {index in
                 HomeWidget()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This above example is just to clarify the question, the code is not compiling.

Comment: The current example is too broad - please specify exactly what do you need. How is it dynamic? What and when should change?

Comment: I need to let the user pick different widget types depending on the user database contents.

Comment: Then for now it looks like it's not possible - see https://stackoverflow.com/q/63797991/8697793

Comment: This is not currently possible. Instead you should offer all (theoretically) possible widgets and show some information in the widget to take action in the app to enable it. I think Apple shows how this could work in https://developer.apple.com/wwdc20/10194 (11:11) where you would dynamically provide options using an Intent and if there are "no user database contents" you could show a text guiding the user to login or select/create content.