# SwiftUI iOS14 Widget - Create create multi layout with the same WidgetFamily

Tags: swift, swiftui, widget, ios14, widgetkit

When I add widgets from home screens, I can see that the Clock application created by Apple has two small `WidgetFamily` layouts.

How to make two small Widgets like in the Clock application?

I see that I only can create one layout for every `WidgetFamily`.

Comment: @pawello2222 Thank you so much. That is the what I need :D

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It seems that you need to create separate Widgets with their own view, entry, provider...

Here is a possible solution using `WidgetBundle`:

1. Create separate Widgets (make sure the `@main` annotation is **not** attached to any of them):

```
struct Widget1: Widget {
    let kind: String = "Widget1"

    var body: some WidgetConfiguration {
        StaticConfiguration(kind: kind, provider: Widget1Provider()) { entry in
            Widget1Entry(entry: entry)
        }
        .configurationDisplayName("Widget1")
        .description("This is an example widget v1.")
    }
}

struct Widget2: Widget {
    let kind: String = "Widget2"

    var body: some WidgetConfiguration {
        ...
    }
}

...
```

2. For each Widget create its own View (possibly also separate Entries and Providers, depending on what you need):

```
struct Widget1EntryView: View {
    var entry: Widget1Entry

    var body: some View {
        Text("Widget1")
    }
}

struct Widget2EntryView: View {
    var entry: Widget2Entry

    var body: some View {
        Text("Widget2")
    }
}

...
```

3. Use `WidgetBundle` to provide a *bundle* containing your Widgets:

```
@main
struct WidgetsBudle: WidgetBundle {
    var body: some Widget {
        Widget1()
        Widget2()
        // add more Widgets if you want
    }
}
```

Note that `@main` is attached to `WidgetsBudle` and not to Widgets.

Comment: Hi @pawello2222, Can I take the loop in the WidgetBundle?

Comment: @CarsonVo Currently it's not possible - see https://stackoverflow.com/q/63797991/8697793